# How can you tell why full page cache is not working on a category page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, debugging

I have enabled full page cache on a Magento2 site which has had quite a few modifications. It does not seem to be taking effect however and I know that if any of the blocks on the page are set to be cacheable="false" then the whole page will not cache. Is there anyway to tell what blocks on a page are cacheable and what is not so that I can ensure that full page cache is enabled? Or is this not possible?

Comment: does it cache any other page besides categories? What does Store > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache > Caching Application say? built-in or varnish?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, in my case it is built-in cache. Can you please help?